# How To Bulk Delete Duplicate Posts from two Wordpress sites

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have one domain with two directories-

1. mysite .com/folder-1
2. mysite. com/folder-2

Two wp have been installed and two DB also.

There are some duplicate posts on the two sites with the same title and slugs like-

mysite .com/*folder-1*/**stackoverflow-how-to-delete-dup-posts**

mysite .com/*folder-2*/**stackoverflow-how-to-delete-dup-posts**

In folder 1 I have 300K+ wp posts

In folder 2 I have 500K+ wp posts

Now I want to delete the posts from the folder-2 directory only.

**Q. Now how can I bulk delete the post from the folder-2 directory only?**

I have already tried the "Delete Duplicate Posts" Plugin by cleverplugins .com. But this plugin can run on a single database/ single wp site only :(

Answer (score 0):

First you should create user to access two databases. Then in second database write query like this:

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.guid = db1.wp_posts.guid;
```

I recommend first backup your databases.